# in some places when we are working with cables at home we get shock and therefore we are thrown away

Tags: electricity, shock

In some places when we are working with cables at home we get shock and therefore we are thrown away.. but in some places like Asia when you get a shock you are stuck with the cable until someone closes the breaker ..Why this sticking and throwing happens?

Comment: I expect it depends mostly on what path the current takes.  what country is "home"

Comment: You claim it depends on the country/part of the world. Do you have references for that? I call bullshit and claim it just depends on chance, or other factors (humidity, quality of earthing, ...). You shouldn't make bold assumptions like that in a post. It invalidates the question if they're false.

Comment: @dim Much more to do with understanding what "let go" threshold is.

Comment: Install a "Ground Fault circuit interrupter" (GFCI) so current not returning via your cable will interrupt the current flow, possibly saving your life for another time & place.

Answer (score 2):

There are different reasons for this to happen.  The first and most important concept to understand is the "let-go current".  The "Let Go" threshold is the current level where we lose control of our muscles and the electricity causes muscles to contract until the current is removed.  Therefore, this would explain why you would be stuck to the cable until current is removed from the wire.

The voltage in each country is different for typical household supplies.  Here is the list for each country: [Voltage by Country](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/).  For example, China, which uses 220V, 50Hz for domestic appliances and the United States uses 120V, 60Hz for domestic appliances.  If we consider a simple wire with a certain resistance (R) and we use it either in China or United States, we will draw different amount of current.  This could be enough difference to enter "let go" threshold.  But it also depends on your body resistance and where the current travels.

> The minimum current a human can feel depends on the current type (AC or DC) as well as frequency for AC. A person can feel at least 1 mA (rms) of AC at 60 Hz, while at least 5 mA for DC. At around 10 milliamperes, AC current passing through the arm of a 68-kilogram (150 lb) human can cause powerful muscle contractions; the victim is unable to voluntarily control muscles and cannot release an electrified object.[5] This is known as the "let go threshold" and is a criterion for shock hazard in electrical regulations.
>
> The current may, if it is high enough and is delivered at sufficient voltage, cause tissue damage or fibrillation which can cause cardiac arrest; more than 30 mA[6] of AC (rms, 60 Hz) or 300 – 500 mA of DC at high voltage can cause fibrillation.[7][8] A sustained electric shock from AC at 120 V, 60 Hz is an especially dangerous source of ventricular fibrillation because it usually exceeds the let-go threshold, while not delivering enough initial energy to propel the person away from the source. However, the potential seriousness of the shock depends on paths through the body that the currents take.